# C++ Plugin architecture design

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I have a generic design issue. I am creating a small application that provides a simple SDK to create DLL plugins. A plugin will register some parameters to the app, so the user can fill them somehow in the GUI and the app will set back those values for the plugin:

```
struct Param{ const char* name; Value value };
```

An exported DLL function `GetList()` will give the GUI the list of params. The user can change those and send them back to the DLL using another exported function `SetParam(...)`. The issue is exactly the choice of `Value`. At the moment I am using `variant<int,float,string>`, but probably there is a better way to make it more flexible and extendable? If I have to add a list of params grouped in a ComboBox, this solution is not OK. Probably I need to have several classes for them, like `IntParam`, `ComboboxParam`, etc. I would like to know other opinions.

Comment: C++ is a strongly-typed language. The type of every object must be known at compile time. There are no exceptions to this rule. Therefore, for something like that, you will have to probably also provide some generic definition of what a value is, and the operation that can be done on that value, so that the main code does not need to know the type of the value. Something a little bit more fleshed out than `std::any`.

Comment: Maybe [Reflection](http://www.vollmann.com/en/pubs/meta/meta/meta.html)?

Comment: `1` You don't stand a snowflake's chance in hell of ever transferring C++ objects across a DLL boundary. `2` COM has solved this issue for you more than 2 decades ago.

Comment: @pptaszni That looks interesting but seems a bit over-engineering?

Comment: @IInspectable Not sure what you mean exactly, I don't think most of the software out there is using COM to provide plugin mechanisms.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a well-defined ABI. That means, you cannot pass C++ objects from code compiled with one compiler to code compiled with a different compiler (or even the same compiler, using a different version, or just different compiler options). At a minimum, your interface is going to be C, but even that doesn't address the issue revolving around allocators. You are free to do some research, but you'll find that all applications that provide a plugin interface either use COM, or provide their own system that replicates COM's guarantees (ABI, allocators, threading models).